# Easy way to install TeX Live (and TeX Studio) in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: latex

I have recently switched to using Linux (Ubuntu 12.04) and I need to install a LaTeX distribution and editor. I'm reasonably experienced with LaTeX on Win7, so is there an easy way to get LaTeX up and running?

Comment: In 14.04 Ubuntu has the TeXLive 2013 packaged --- chances are that 12.04 has quite an old version. Depending on what you do, YMMV. Read the answer by @tatjana-heuser and then choose from there...

Comment: Related: [How to install “vanilla” TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu) at TeX.SE.

Comment: There are directions on TeXstudio's sourceforge wiki here: http://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/wiki/Compiling/#linux

Answer (score 11):

It's probably best to download an `.iso` image of a TeX distribution from [CTAN](http://ctan.unsw.edu.au/systems/texlive/Images/), `texlive2013.iso` for example - it's ~2GB. Put this into your `Downloads` folder.

Just ensure that you have the `perl-tk` package installed before using the GUI. If not, open a terminal and go:

```
$ apt-get install perl-tk
```

Then create a mount point:

```
$ sudo mkdir /mnt
```

Change the current directory, mount the `.iso` and start installation

```
$ cd ~/Downloads
$ sudo mount -t iso9660 -o ro,loop,noauto texlive2013.iso /mnt
$ cd /mnt
$ sudo ./install-tl --gui=perltk
```

This opens up a nice GUI. You can to decide what to install in `Installation collections`. Also change the `Create symlinks in system directories`  as in the screenshot so that the directories will be all laid out for you. This means you won't need to poke around and modify your system files post-installation.

[image: perltk]

After installation, close the terminal and open a new terminal:

```
$ sudo umount /mnt
```

Check if everything is OK:

```
$ tex --version

TeX 3.1415926 (TeX Live 2013)
kpathsea version 6.1.1
Copyright 2013 D.E. Knuth.
```

Try processing a .tex file and preview a PostScript file.

```
$ latex sample2e.tex
$ dvips sample2e.dvi
```

You can also make a .pdf file:

```
$ pdflatex sample2e.tex
```

If you want to modify settings or get more packages, do this in TeX Live Manager 2013:

```
$ sudo tlmgr -gui
```

To install a LaTeX editor, (e.g. TeX Studio), download the relevant `.deb` file into Downloads folder and install

```
$ cd ~/Downloads
$ sudo dpkg -i texstudio_2.7.0_i386.deb
```

You may need to install `libpoppler-qt4-3.deb` first.

References:

[TUG documentation](http://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-iso.html)

[TeX Live docs](http://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.pdf)

[Starlinq blog](http://starlinq.livejournal.com/5489.html)

Comment: +1 for effort but you're kind of reinventing the wheel here. The LaTeX packages are available in the Ubuntu repositories.

Comment: @terdon Cheers. I just wanted to share what I did after the [Starlinq blog](http://starlinq.livejournal.com/5489.html) confused me so much.

Comment: And thank you very much for taking the effort to post this! For future reference though, just use the ones from the repos as I show in my answer. It is much easier to install that way and _much_ easier to upgrade and deal with all the packages.

Comment: +1 - good documentation, and the way to go if you want an up-to-date texlive installation. Unfortunately, the one in the repos has a tendency to lag behind quite significantly. Also the way to go if you're running texlive on several platforms and prefer to keep them in sync. (Or you'll never stop tracing back why your book project develops half a page offset by page 916, when translated on a different system. (Leading to a file going to print with all the don't-wrap-at-this-point  tweaks done in vain and all the horrors in print))

Comment: after following all your steps I am being told that The program 'tex' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install texlive-binaries

Comment: @MedullaOblongata it should be `sudo tlmgr --gui` with two dashes, not `-gui`

Answer (score 11):

Just install the relevant packages from the repositories:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-base
```

That will get you a basic LaTeX system. For a more complete installation with more packages and fonts, use this:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-base texlive-latex-extra texlive-latex-recommended texlive-fonts-recommended
```

Comment: This certainly qualifies as *easiest* installation, if somewhat incomplete since Ubuntu only packages a subset of the packages available through tlmgr, and some are outdated compared to ctan. If texlive is needed in a productive environment, it may be better to do a vanilla texlive installation with tlmgr updates for better control of syncronous installations and better control when things are updated. (Never update during the final preprint stages of an important document...)

Comment: On Ubuntu 12.04 this will install TexLive 2009, not at all recommended. There are multiple issues with the modules in the `texlive-latex-extra` package that prevent successful compilation of various features.

Answer (score 2):

Three ways to go:

- Install the Ubuntu packages for texlive. Described by terdon, Easiest, but they've a tendency to be outdated and only a subset of what would be available through the [tlmgr](https://www.tug.org/texlive/tlmgr.html).
- Install texlive from the latest iso image. Described by Medulla Oblongata. Currently available: 2013 - outdated by almost a year, so the first step after installation would be to update it using [tlmgr](https://www.tug.org/texlive/tlmgr.html).
- Install using the network installer available at [tug.org](http://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html). This actually is easy, and I'd recommend it, especially if you want to keep installations across different platforms in sync.

see also: [How do I update my TeX distribution?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55437/how-do-i-update-my-tex-distribution) on [tex.sx](http://tex.stackexchange.com), especially for the first (community wiki) answer explaining the TeX Live update scheme.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use  **Kile - an Integrated LaTeX Environment**.

You can easily install it from **ubuntu software center**.

[image]

Comment: Yes, but Kile is just an editor. You still need a LaTeX distribution to run it. While installing `kile` through the repos will bring in most of the needed packages, that's a pretty roundabout way of installing LaTeX _and_ you end up with extra stuff you don't need as well as missing some basic LaTeX packages that won't be listed as `kile` dependencies.

Comment: Thank you... I didnt knew that. I used Kile for making presentations and report making during my degree days, without much difficulties :)

Answer (score 0):

The most recent version of TeX Live packaged for Ubuntu 12.04 is 2012, which is available from the [TeX Live back-ports PPA](https://launchpad.net/~texlive-backports/+archive/ubuntu/ppa). It is relatively easy to install from the terminal, start by removing any absolute packages that may be installed:

```
sudo apt-get remove texlive*
```

Then add the PPA and update:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:texlive-backports/ppa
sudo apt-get update
```

Finally install:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive
```

This will install the most common modules. If you come to need more specific modules then you will have to install the "extra" package (which at the last check was almost 1 Gb):

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-extra
```

For someone coming from Windows I would recommend [TexMaker](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/) as GUI (available from the Software Centre). This is what we feed to students and they manage mostly well with it.

Answer (score 0):

I ran `sudo apt-get install texlive-full` which has some of the disadvantages listed above including that it might not be super-up-to-date, but I've not found any problems. (Yet)

Has the advantage that it just installs everything in one quick command. Some may argue this is bad practice / a waste of hard disk space - but I use ubuntu because it's quick and (usually) works, not because it saves me a few hundred megabytes of disk space over other linux distros...