# "The program 'tex' is currently not installed" error after texlive installation on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, texlive

I tried to install texlive 2014 on Ubuntu 12.04 using downloaded .iso image file.
There are some instructions in the following link:
[Easy way to install TeX Live (and TeX Studio) in Ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/457323/easy-way-to-install-tex-live-and-tex-studio-in-ubuntu-12-04)
After installation completed successfully I tried to check if everything is OK using the following command:
"tex --version"
but I got the error:
"The program 'tex' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install texlive-binaries"
how can I fix this problem to use latest version of texlive on my computer?

Comment: Have you created the symbolic links to /usr/local/bin during the installation ? If not you'll probably need to set your path variable to include the tex bin directory.

Comment: No I didn't. How can I do that? (Actually I'm new to Ubuntu)

Comment: Do you know the exact directory that texlive was installed ? Why don't you install the ones from the repositories directly using `sudo apt-get install texlive` at the terminal ?

Comment: Seems like we need more upvotes on an answer in that question which doesn't suggest to install from TeX Live ISO and install from the packages instead.

Comment: I installed it to it's default path : (/usr/local/texlive). I didn't use repositories because they have the old version of Texlive.

Comment: You can run `tlmgr -gui` at the terminal and make sure the symbolic links are created. Look here at Figure 10 for the gui in `https://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#tlportable` . You might need to locate where `tlmgr` was installed first. To do that use `sudo updatedb` followed by `locate tlmgr`

Comment: Your last Comment works. thanks for your help Harris.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's important that you just don't follow instructions blindly and also that you make decisions that are appropriate for you. If you're just a beginner choosing the default options and [preferring (TeX) packages from the Ubuntu repositories](https://askubuntu.com/a/457328/40581) over external sources is the best option.

## Stop here and read the last paragraph again...

Really.

## Cause

The [instructions you probably followed](https://askubuntu.com/a/457324/40581) suggested to *not* install symlinks, which is why all the resources, like binaries and manpages, are not in your environment (`PATH` variable) and Ubuntu doesn't know where these are installed or even if they are installed installed.

[image]

Also note the directories in the screenshot for a hint if you don't know where you installed TeX live (assuming that these aren't customized).

[image]

## Correcting the mistake

As the instructions don't seem to provide how to setup the missing symlinks¹, reinstalling to the same location as before, but this time with creating symlinks option enabled, would be one option.

The other option would be to remove what TeX live installed (seems to be in `/usr/local` but `/opt` is also a possible location, **only** remove files and directories related to `textlive`, other programs may have stored files there too, more details see [FHS](https://askubuntu.com/q/138547/40581)) and install the version from the repositories. Upgrade to a newer LTS release if you need a newer version of TeX Live

¹ Possbily related: [How to install “vanilla” TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95373)

Comment: I reinstall it and this time I check "Create symlinks In system directories" and every thing is OK this time. Thanks a lot.

Comment: If following your first solution, reinstalling everything as before, will it overwrite the previous install, or will I have two version installed? Does it see that everything is already there and simply progress to creating the symlinks?

Comment: I'm not sure, better look for a way to remove the old parts first.