# Install TeX Live on Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, latex

I'm trying to install texlive2014 from http://ctan.asis.io/tex-archive/systems/texlive/
and I get all of the packages. At the first step of the installation process I get this error:

```
~$ cd TEXLIVE
~/TEXLIVE$ dir
install-tl             persian-bib
install-tl-20150219        README
install-tl-20150221        readme-html.dir
install-tl-20150221        readme-txt.dir
install-tl-advanced.bat        rsync.pm
install-tl.html            Selfupdate.pm
install-tl.nsi             UpdateShowDVI.tpl
install-tl.texi            update-tlmgr-latest.exe
install-tl-unx.tar.gz       update-tlmgr-latest.exe.sha256
install-tl-unx.tar.gz          update-tlmgr-latest.sh
install-tl-unx.tar.gz.sha256   update-tlmgr-latest.sh.sha256
install-tl-windows.bat         update-tlmgr-r35898.exe
install-tl-windows.exe         update-tlmgr-r35898.exe.sha256
install-tl-windows.exe.sha256  update-tlmgr-r35923.sh
install-tl.zip             update-tlmgr-r35923.sh.sha256
install-tl.zip.sha256          updateWidgets.al
lpxsetup.updateinfo
~/TEXLIVE$ sudo install install-tl
[sudo] password for asemaneh: 
install: missing destination file operand after ‘install-tl’
Try 'install --help' for more information.
```

My machine is an Asus Eee PC 32-bit & it has Ubuntu 14.10 and is updated.
What is the problem?

Comment: I think you're supposed to run the `install-tl` *file* (which appears to be a perl script), **not** run the `install` **command** with `install-tl` as an argument - so something like `chmod +x install-tl ; sudo ./install-tl`

Comment: ,hi,I think the apt-get is an operation that is used for install from soft (online sources),but I`m trying to install TeX Live in package mode & this way  is recommended for TeX Live & so I just need to get the packages from CTAN and exited those from zip and install, also I try the install perl , but it dos`t work !@asemaneh4

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to install texlive2014 […]

Go to Ubuntu Software Center and search for `texlive`. You will find [this](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/texlive/).

> What is the problem?

Good question, what is ***your*** problem?

> at the first step of install process I have this error :
>
> ```
> asemaneh@asemaneh-1025C:~$ cd TEXLIVE
> asemaneh@asemaneh-1025C:~/TEXLIVE$ dir
> ```

Which installation process? Does it really tell you to run `dir`? It's a very unusual choice for listing directory contents.

> ```
> $ sudo install install-tl
> [sudo] password for asemaneh: 
> install: missing destination file operand after ‘install-tl’
> Try 'install --help' for more information.
> ```

That is not an error message! That is a *completely* **unrelated program** (`install`) to *this* installation process telling you "*That is not the way I want to be used! Run me again with the `--help` parameter and I will tell you how I should be used and what I can do*". While it is completely unrelated, it's trying to be really nice to you. Here is the quote from the 2nd sentence:

> If you want to download and install a ready-to-use
>   package on a GNU/Linux system, **you should instead be using a package manager**
>   like yum(1) or apt-get(1).

In other words use the Ubuntu Software Center, as I already suggested.

If you still want or need to install this particular version (I don't see why, 14.10 has 2014 too) and want to take care of all updates yourself, then go to the official project site (you can use Wikipedia to find it) and follow the [instructions](https://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html) properly. Include a reference to the particular step of these instructions if you *really* encounter an error. Also this question has already been asked and answered: [Easy way to install TeX Live (and TeX Studio) in Ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/q/457323/40581)

I just spent valuable time where somebody else could have just marked your question as a duplicate without telling you that `install` is not the right command to install software, that you should prefer software from the Software Center and that you should follow instructions properly instead running of arbitrary commands that come to your mind. Of course you are free to continue with low effort approaches to your problems, if you want low effort and inaccurate answers when seeking for help in the future.

Comment: hi,I think the apt-get is an operation that is used for install from soft (online sources)

Comment: @ASEMANEH4 `apt-get install <package name>` does install software, yes.